# Arabic unicode with MigraDoc

Tags: vb.net, migradoc

Despite the correct options for pdfRender in MigraDoc

Dim pdfRenderer As New PdfDocumentRenderer(True, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Default)

i get unclear result after generating the pdf file.

so how to render the document unicode for arabic text ?

Comment: According to the PDFsharp and MigraDoc wiki, RTL languages are not supported. [Does_PDFsharp_support_for_Arabic_Hebrew_CJK_Chinese_Japanese_Korean_6](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx#Does_PDFsharp_support_for_Arabic_Hebrew_CJK_Chinese_Japanese_Korean_6)

Comment: Without knowing your requirements, http://www.evopdf.com/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx might meet them.